# How do I write a SonarQube plugin extension being able to access all ASTs of all files?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I develop a language plugin for SonarQube.

For now I am able to produce an AST for all files, do per file checks etc, all works well.

But now I need to perform cross-file checks and calculate cross-file metrics; and for this I need to be able to access all ASTs generated by all files.

Unfortunately I am completely unable to do that. I have asked the question on the dev@ mailing list and couldn't get a clear answer, and reading the online documentation and plowing through the source of existing plugins have been of no help either.

How do you perform such a feature?

Comment: FYI, none of the existing SonarQube language plugins are doing such kind of thing so I guess that's why you don't get a clear answer from the dev mailing list.

Comment: @FreddyMallet-SonarSource Java does it to a certain extent -- at least cross file checks (shadowing for instance). I since came up with my own solution but it's kind of ugly :/

Comment: For Java and C#, the analyzers are also relying on the bytecode so that's the way to get semantic information from external source files. And so this is not by working on several AST at same time.